# Import passwords from Chrome to Firefox Quantum doesn't work

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have seen theses instructions: https://www.howtogeek.com/333047/how-to-migrate-all-your-data-from-chrome-to-firefox/ but the dialog box on my firefox doesn't show the 'Saved Password' choice.  The Firefox version is 57.0 for ubuntu.  I am running lubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution in Firefox.

1. Go to about:config
2. Click the Accept the Risk and Continue when Proceed with Caution page appears so that you can open the File Configuration page.
3. Paste the following preference name in the “search preference name” box and press the Enter.

   ```
   signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled
   ```
4. Then, you can check whether the option is enabled. If yes, the “True” tag will show up. If disabled, you will see a “False” tag.
5. If the “False” tag occurs, it means that preferences are disabled. So you need to click the toggle button to turn it to “True” to turn on Import from a file option

Open Firefox and click the Menu icon. Then select the Logins and Passwords option.

From here easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is under bookmarks -> Show all bookmarks

Show all bookmarks -> Import and Backup -> Import Data from Another Browser

[image: Bookmarks]

[image: Chromium]

from another browser.

Will post screen shots in a few minutes

Comment: I can select chrome or chromium, but neither then offer the choice of saved passwords to import.

Comment: It works on firefox from Mozilla, if it does not work on Ubuntu you found a bug -> file a bug report on launchpad . You could try downloading from mozilla as a work around. https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/57.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/

Comment: I believe this is indeed a bug. The only workaround I found was to do the import in Windows, then use Firefox sync to load the passwords in Ubuntu.